# Crystal Report unable to generate in VS 2012

Tags: crystal-reports

Bobj is undefined error when I used debug in VS 2012. tried everything but I am running out of ideas why my crystal report is unable to work.

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  --><configuration>
    <configSections>
      <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
      <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
        <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
          <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler,CrystalDecisions.Shared,Version=13.0.2000.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304,Custom=null"/>
          <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>


    </configSections>

  <appSettings>
      <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />
      <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />
      <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20130616171922;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20130616171922.mdf"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/></assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  <httpHandlers><add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/></httpHandlers></system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/></handlers><validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
    <businessObjects>
      <crystalReports>
        <rptBuildProvider>

          <add embedRptInResource="true"/>
          <crystalReportViewer>

            <add key="ResourceUri" value="~/crystalreportviewers13"/>
          </crystalReportViewer>

        </rptBuildProvider>
      </crystalReports>
    </businessObjects>

  </configuration>
```

InvoiceReport.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="InvoiceReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.InvoiceReport" %>
<%@ Register assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" tagprefix="CR" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">



    <p>
        <br />
        Invoice Report</p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True"  Height="1202px" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" ToolPanelView="None" ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="950px" HasCrystalLogo="False" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="false" HasToggleParameterPanelButton="false" EnableParameterPrompt="False" />
    <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
        <Report FileName="CrystalReport1.rpt">
        </Report>
    </CR:CrystalReportSource>

    <p>
    </p>



</asp:Content>
```

InvoiceReport.cs

```
public partial class InvoiceReport : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        CrystalReport1 m_Invoicerpt = null;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            ReportDocument crystaldoc = new ReportDocument();
            crystaldoc.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport1.rpt"));
            crystaldoc.SetDatabaseLogon("xx","xx",@"xx","xx");
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource=crystaldoc;
        }
    }
}
```

would like to know how to make the crystal reports work. OS is in windows7
used v_13_0_5 and supportpack 5
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

using .net framework 4.5 in my web application project